# Are the Ancient Humanoids and the Preservers the only extinct advanced aliens civilisations in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

The [Ancient Humanoids](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient_humanoid) who are believed to have seeded the Milky Way and the [Preservers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Preservers) who Spock identified as a "Super Race" and who rescued primitive cultures from extinction and then seeded them elsewhere are both examples of extinct advanced alien civilisation that existed within Star Trek.

Are these the only examples of such a race within Star Trek?

To be included as an answer a race should be:

- Extinct
- More advanced than the Federation in the Next Generation/DS9/Voyager era.

Comment: The iconians, the race that left behind the skin of evil, etc etc. The Galaxy is littered with ancient advanced civilisations

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tkon_Empire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a few, though of course it can be hard to say for certain whether a species is definitely extinct. (I don't know of any indication the Preservers are - they must have visited Earth perhaps a thousand years before the episode where they're referenced, for example.)

The big conspicuous examples of past civilizations with advanced technology now thought to be extinct are the [T'kon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tkon_Empire) (their sun went supernova 600,000 years ago) and the [Iconians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Iconian_Empire) (their homeworld was bombarded 200,000 years ago). The [D'Arsay](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/D%27Arsay) were active 87 million years ago, and the ability of their archives to survive into the present day and wreak havoc on Federation ships can be argued to indicate a higher technology level.

The [Makers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Makers) of the androids in the episode I, Mudd apparently traveled from the Andromeda galaxy and manufactured advanced androids, but went extinct.

The [Minosians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Minosian) were wiped out by their own weapon systems, which appear to have been more advanced than TNG-era Starfleet technology. The [Husnock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Husnock) are hard to categorize with certainty since the evidence we see of their capabilities is fabricated, so they may have been technological peers of the Federation prior to their extinction.

There are a couple of interesting edge cases in [Apollo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apollo) and [Sargon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arretan), both examples where one or a handful of an advanced ancient species survived into the present day but then apparently went extinct on camera. You could also quibble about whether a species which transforms itself into pure energy has effectively gone extinct in its original form, though I don't know of an example where an entire species does this at once. A close case might be the [Vagrans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vagran) who created Armus, the "skin of evil".